# Enabling/installing GD extension? --without-gd

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, gd

How does one enable (or perhaps I need to install) GD when my phpinfo() output in "Configure Command" says; --without-gd ?

I also have nothing in my phpinfo() output "Core" that lists "gd"

PHP Version 5.2.4 on AWS.

Comment: I have same problem but I would like to remind question is not how to setup gd on terminal or how to restart your server question is after all if you can not see on phpinfo file gd support what should you do?
one of answer on php.net [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php)
it says you should configure your php --with-gd="your diroctory path to gd"

Answer (score 102):

if you are on a Debian based server (such as Ubuntu) you can run the following command:

```
apt-get install php-gd
```

Then once it is complete run:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This will restart your server and enable GD in PHP.

If you are on another type of system you will need to use something else (like yum install) or compile directly into PHP.

Comment: There should be an "gd" section in the phpinfo().  

Something like:  
GD Support enabled

Comment: @Shu - Did my suggestion end up working?  Just wanting to see if that was the issue.

Comment: On Redhat and variants including Fedora, the command is: `yum install php-gd` and then `apachectl restart`.

Comment: extension=gd in php.ini without ; so uncommented in new php

Answer (score 76):

For **PHP8** use (**php8.1-gd** are also available):

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd
```

For PHP7.0 use (**php7.1-gd, php7.2-gd, php7.3-gd and php7.4-gd** are also available):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

and than **restart your webserver**.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

or

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: From a while now, every extension is  now on Ubuntu  aliased. IE `sudo apt-get install php-gd` refers  to the running version.

Answer (score 25):

Check if in your php.ini file has the following line:

```
;extension=php_gd2.dll
```

if exists, change it to

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

and restart apache

(it works on MAC)

Comment: You don't even need to restart your webserver if you are on terminal

Comment: I  don't have `php_gd2.dll` extention

Comment: In my case there's `extension=gd` and then `;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1`, but no `;extension=php_gd2.dll`. As I [read](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/gd2-gd-windows), this is the case with PHP8. Still I get an error, despite `php -m` clearly showing `gd` extension is available. Odd.

Answer (score 17):

In my case (`php 5.6`, `Ubuntu 14.04`) the following command worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

According to php version we need to change the `php5.x-gd`

Answer (score 17):

**PHP7 Or PHP8 For Windows:**

Check if in your php.ini file has the following line:

```
;extension=gd
```

if exists, change it to

```
extension=gd
```

if not found, Add this

```
extension=gd
```

and restart apache

(it works on WINDOWS)

Answer (score 12):

All previous answers are correct but were not sufficient for me on ArchLinux. I also needed to edit `/etc/php/php.ini` and to uncomment :

```
;extension=gd.so
```

The initial `;` on the line needs to be removed. 
After restarting Nginx via `systemctl restart nginx`, I was good to go.

Comment: Nice, 2019 here on arch, I had installed GD extension with `yay -S php-gd` but that didn't setup the php.ini/conf.d/gd.ini like it should have. Your tip worked. The AUR probably needs its build file updated to do that.3 minutes later... oh that package has been flagged as out of date, looks like `php70-gd` is the _one_.

Comment: For php 7.3 open php.ini and ucomment `extension=gd2`

Answer (score 3):

For `php7.1` do:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

and restart webserver. For `apache` do

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Enable gd via XAMPP in windows

First stop the server and go to config

[image]

Find the `;extension=gd`

[image]

Remove the `;` and save

[image]

and start the server then you will fixed the issue.

Comment: On production enviroment, you probably don't  want to stop the service for that long.

Answer (score 2):

If You're using php5.6 and Ubuntu 18.04 Then run these two commands in your terminal your errors will be solved definitely.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

then restart your apache server by this command.

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I've PHP 7.3 and Nginx 1.14 on Ubuntu 18.

```
# it installs php7.3-gd for the moment
# and restarts PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager: php-fpm7.3.
sudo apt-get install php-gd

# after I've restarted Nginx
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Works!

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS (but the same may apply to other distros too) if you install the php7x-gd module followed by Apache restart and still the `php -i` does not show the `GD Support => enabled` it might mean that the php.ini was not automatically configured to support this extension.

All you have to to is either to edit the `/etc/php/php.ini` or to create a `/etc/php.d/gd.ini` file with the following content:

```
[gd]
extension=/path/to/gd.so # use the gd.so absolute path here
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

I am using PHP 8
I had to search for `;extension=gd` in my `php.ini` file. Then removed the `;` and error has gone.