# Heroku - how to enable gd on heroku php application?

Tags: php, heroku, gd

Heroku said:

> The following built-in extensions have been built “shared” and can be enabled through composer.json (internal identifier names given in parentheses):

But it doesn't give an example, I tried with the following composer.json:

`{
    "require": {
        "gd": "*"
    }
}`

But when I `git push heroku master`, I get:

> My composer.json:
>   
>   `{
>       "require": {
>           "gd": "*"
>       }
>   }`

But when I `git push heroku master`, I get:

```
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.0.0-alpha9-19-g10401d5 2014-12-09 11:32:02
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies
       Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

         Problem 1
           - The requested package gd could not be found in any version, there may be a typo     in the package name.

       Potential causes:
        - A typo in the package name
        - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-    stability setting
          see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

       Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

How can I enable gd on heroku???

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try it with:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-gd": "*"
    }
}
```

see here [using-optional-extensions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions)

Comment: Note, this solution should be contained in a .json text file in the root directory of your project (same directory as your .git folder). Commit and push these changes and they should take affect.

Comment: `Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.`

and I can't install it from sudo as `sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd` says `sudo: command not found`

Comment: Thank you! Saved me from a massive headache! +1

Comment: After this modification, you need to run `composer update` so your changes are reflected in composer.lock

Answer (score 4):

Just adding GD as dependency (require) in composer does not load the extension GD. It just tells that this package needs gd enabled. "ext-gd" is just a virtual package, not existing for real.

you have to **install** it on your platform.

see here [composer - platform-packages](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#platform-packages)

Comment: For those who are confused: ensure you have installed php*.*-gd (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2283199/4900327), then run `composer update` in your repo directory, and optionally add `vendor/*` to your .gitignore

Comment: @abhidivekar how do you run apt-get on heroku?   when I try apt-get in `heroku run bash` shell I get read-only errors preventing me from installing.  php info says compiled `--with-gd=shared` though, it's confusing.

Comment: Found out it had to do with getting it installed locally.

Comment: well explained. This should be the correct answer. Thanks