# trying to install ext-gd on heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5, gd

i tried adding `"ext-gd": "*"` to my `composer.json` file
([Heroku - how to enable gd on heroku php application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380365/heroku-how-to-enable-gd-on-heroku-php-application))

but when i run `composer update` on the server, i get this response back

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.`

what do i do to install `gd extension`, im trying to use laravel's socialite library to retrieve the avatar from a user`s profile and this is where it crashes

**UPDATE**:

when i use the command `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

it doesnt throw an error response, but it doesnt fix the issue, i still get this message thrown back when i try to retrieve the avatar image:

`GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.`

thanks to anyone who helps

Answer (score 0):

Just adding GD as dependency (require) in composer does not load the extension GD. It just tells that this package needs gd enabled. "ext-gd" is just a virtual package, not existing for real.

you have to **install** it on your platform.

see here [composer - platform-packages](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#platform-packages)

Look at the error message. It tells you exactly whats wrong! GD Library ext is not available.

This answer here is nearly the same as my answer in the post you linked: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40398281/6104816)