# Image converting in PHP

Tags: php, html, php-extension

I have a book where is a sample for creating a whole new picture, from a random picture given by the user, and I think there is something wrong in the example, at least I can't use it. The error code gave back by the PHP in the browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromstring() in C:\xampp\htdocs\kepkonvertalas.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kepkonvertalas.php on line 13
```

The HTML form:

```
<form action="kepkonvertalas.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="kep"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="kuldes">
</form>
```

The PHP part:

```
<?php
 $fajl = $_FILES['kep']['tmp_name'];
 $kep = file_get_contents($fajl);
 $forraskep = imagecreatefromstring($kep);
 $szelesseg = imageSX($forraskep);
 $magassag = imageSY($forraskep);
 $ujmagassag = 400;
 $ujszelesseg = $ujmagassag*($szelesseg/$magassag);
 $ujkep = imagecreatetruecolor($ujszelesseg, $ujmagassag);
 $eredmeny = imagecopyresampled($ujkep, $forraskep, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ujszelesseg, $ujmagassag, $szelesseg, $magassag);
 imagejpeg($ujkep, "ujkep.jpg");
?>
<img src="ujkep.jpg" alt="">`
```

What is suspect, is that this extension is not implemented into my `php.ini`, but I cant find any proof for it, either solve the problem. Thanks for the help!

I tried to implement a picture from an URL, and do the conversion on that, which means I deleted the

```
$fajl = $_FILES['kep']['tmp_name'];
$kep = file_get_contents($fajl);`
```

And I've made a variable with a picture URL, and in the
`$forraskep = imagecreatefromstring($kep);`

I just changed like this:

`$forraskep = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($src);`

Well the next problem was, that the `$forraskep` variable was not defined.

I expect an output where I have the picture with the size of the given parameters.

Comment: Make sure your system has GD library support

Comment: install the PHP GD extension and ensure it's enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling/installing GD extension? --without-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283199/enabling-installing-gd-extension-without-gd)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually kinda easy:

1. open php.ini
2. search for "extension=gd"
3. delete the semicolon
4. restart apache server