# Incompatibility of laravel dependencies on production(deployment using gitlab CI/CD)

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab-ci, vps

I Tried to deploy my laravel project to linux VPS server using gitlab ci/cd and found these problems :

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
    Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
    Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
      Problem 1
        - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.24.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.24.1 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
      Problem 2
        - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode is locked to version 4.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
        - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
      Problem 3
        - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.24.1 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
        - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.40 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.24.1].
        - maatwebsite/excel is locked to version 3.1.40 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

This is my .gitlab-ci file script :

```
script:
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "git config --global safe.directory '*'"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "if [ ! -d $VAR_DIREKTORI/.git ]; then echo 'Project belum ditemukan di direktori $VAR_DIREKTORI' && cd $VAR_DIREKTORI && git clone https://oauth2:$VAR_CLONE_KEY@$VAR_GIT_URL_TANPA_HTTP .; fi"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "cd $VAR_DIREKTORI && git pull origin master && exit"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "if [ -d $VAR_DIREKTORI/.env ]; then rm .env; fi"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "cd $VAR_DIREKTORI && echo '$VAR_FILE_ENV' >> .env"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "if [ -d $VAR_DIREKTORI/.htaccess ]; then rm .htaccess; fi"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "cd $VAR_DIREKTORI && echo '$VAR_FILE_HTACCESS' >> .htaccess"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "docker exec webserver composer install"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "docker exec webserver composer update"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "docker exec webserver php artisan migrate"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "docker exec webserver php artisan db:seed"
    - ssh $VAR_USER@$VAR_IP "docker exec webserver php artisan key:generate"
    - echo "Done!"
```

As far as i know, the composer update (which i already put on script) will solve this, but the error still occured, how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explains that the extension `gd` is missing from your PHP installation...

`phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.24.1 ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.`

See examples here on how to install it. But you maybe want to google how to install it for your specific OS and PHP version..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37072723/2079735

Comment: this worked as expected , thanks