# How to install GD extension for PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I have *PHP 8.1.2* with *Apache 2.4.52* on *Ubuntu 22.04* and I think I need the *GD Graphics Extension* for my PHP scripts to work but it appears not to be installed and / or enabled (there is no GD section in the output from running `phpinfo()`.

Some [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283199/enabling-installing-gd-extension-without-gd) I have seen is to run `apt-get install php-gd` and restart Apache without any modifications to *php.ini*.

At [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) it seems to suggest there is a

> recommended bundled version of the GD library

already present in my PHP and that I need to edit *php.ini* in order to enable it. I understood (I now think wrongly) this meant I needed to remove the prefixed semi colons from these pre existing directives:

- `;--with-gd[=DIR]`
- `;--enable-gd`

The advice continues on to suggest for certain image formats (although possibly not for *PNG*) I need to uncomment:

- `;--with-jpeg`
- `;--with-xpm`
- `;--with-webp`

For enhancing GD's font capabilities uncomment:

- `--with-XXXX`
- `--with-freetype`

searching */etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini* revealed that was no `;--enable-gd` line or any of the other above directives in that file. There was a `;extension=gd` line.

I would like to know how to proceed from here in order to install (if it is not already installed as I thought the documentation implied) and enable the GD Graphics extension.

**Edit** I also saw this [geeksforgeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-php-gd-in-xampp/) suggesting to uncomment `;extension=gd` and restart the server.

Comment: You're looking at instructions for _building_ GD [and also PHP] where you can _optionally_ build it into core. Most distros build GD separately as an extension, which is what the `php-gd` package is. Depending on which distro and who built the package it may or may not have added the relevant PHP config to enable it. Uncomment the extension line.

Comment: make sure after you changed the php.ini (e.g. uncomment the line) , you restart the httpd

Comment: @Sammitch does that mean I should do `apt-get install php-gd`? Then uncomment `;extension=gd`? Then restart server?

Comment: What version of `PHP` do you have now? You can run `php -v`.  Can you run `which php` and show the log?

Comment: @DreamBold `php -v` gives *PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9 (cli) etc etc* and `which php` gives */usr/bin/php*

Comment: @user3425506 You can try `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd` then

Comment: @DreamBold I did that and did not edit php.ini and now GD section appears in phpinfo() output and also my image handling code is working. Thanks!

Comment: @user3425506 Perfect, let me add it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `php -v` to see what version of PHP you have on the machine.
After that, you can run `sudo apt-get install php<your-php-version>-gd`, e.g. `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd`. Hope it helps!

Comment: `php -v` will give you the PHP version for the CLI, which isn't always the same as the one used for rendering the web. It's best to use `phpinfo()` to be sure (especially when using FPM).