# Laravel file manager says [ object object ] when trying to upload the image to the server

Tags: laravel, unisharp-file-manager

I am using a laravel file manager for uploading an images to the server. In local everything works file but when in the server it always shows [ object object ] with blank images.  But it gets uploaded.

Also, there was a warning message showing "required imgick or gd extension"

[image: laravel file manager]

code

```
<div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <a id="image" data-input="thumbnail" data-preview="holder"
                                                    class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Choose
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                            <input id="thumbnail" class="form-control" type="text" name="thumbnail_image">
                                        </div>
```

```
$('#image').filemanager('image');
```

Comment: "*Also, there was a warning message showing "required imgick or gd extension*" - sounds like it might be the key to the problem, right?  You might want to edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable gd extension check this:
[Enabling/installing GD extension? --without-gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283199/enabling-installing-gd-extension-without-gd)

If Error still persists:
Check lfm.php in /config and check size configuration.

Also Try changing php upload size and post size.

You should be able to check errors for this in dev tools.